# what does Loss Tangent means in capacitor?

Tags: capacitor, capacitance, loss

As we know the definition of Loss Tangent in capacitor which it is:
When a sinusoidal alternating voltage is applied to an ideal capacitor, the current advances by pi/2 in phase. In the case of a practical capacitor, however, advance
in phase is (pi/2 - delta), which is smaller than pi/2. “delta” is referred to as Loss Angle.

**but how we can use it when we are selecting a capacitor?**

Comment: Most designers use ESR (Equivalent Series Resistance) instead. Experienced designers know when ESR might affect the design and calculate its effect when necessary. Good simulation models will include ESR.

Comment: https://www.electronics-notes.com/articles/basic_concepts/capacitance/esr-dissipation-factor-loss-tangent-q.php

Answer (score 1):

Generally we don't worry about the angle *per se*, but the fact that it represents loss. There are two situations where loss is undesired.

In power applications, where loss results in significant heating.
In oscillator and filter applications, where loss results in lower Q.

In both cases, lower loss tangent is better.

There are some situations where ESR is a better expression of performance than loss tangent, although they are related by the capacitance. In power supply decoupling applications, it's a measure of the irreducible ripple that Farads alone cannot shunt. Here smaller ESR is better.

Answer (score 0):

When you place an electric field across a capacitor, it causes the dielectric to [polarize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dielectric). Given a sinusoidal steady state (SSS) voltage across the capacitor, it generates a SSS electric field between the plates at a radian frequency \$\omega\$.

Now conceptually, as \$\omega\$ increases, the polarization of the dielectric fails to keep up with the electric field.  We say P lags E  (Polarization lags Electric Field), which results in the -delta, \$-\delta\$, you mentioned, where the negative comes from the lag.

As P rotates to keep up with E, there is heat generated in this process.  For electricity, we always model heat loss using resistors, hence the term ESR (equivalent series resistance).

The amount P lags E is a function of the dielectric material and \$\omega\$. This means \$\delta\$, Q, ESR, etc. are all a function of material and frequency.  As electrical engineers, we just approximate it as a constant resistance (ESR) in a 1st order circuit model of a real capacitor.

Finally, selecting a capacitor is not as easy as it might seem.  There are trade-offs in capacitance/volume, ESR, Leakage Resistance, Dialectic Absorption, and breakdown voltage, and are very much a function of the application. Kemet has a relatively good [e-book](https://ec.kemet.com/knowledge/introduction-to-capacitors-ebook) that is worth reading.  It is called "What is a Capacitor" in case the link breaks in the future.