# How to read the ESR from datasheets?

Tags: circuit-design, datasheet

I have this capacitor C0603C101K5RAC with the [specification sheet linked here.](https://connect.kemet.com:7667/gateway/IntelliData-ComponentDocumentation/1.0/download/specsheet/C0603C101K5RAC%7BBULK%7D)

How do I find its ESR based on the chart? Is there a frequency I should be basing it on?

Comment: I must confess that I first thought it was a good question because ESR is not always specified. In this case there is a _very obvious and complete chart_. So I don't understand the question here really, how can it be unclear?

Comment: You can see the ESR varies with frequency. In the instance where you might be using this capacitor on the input or output of a switched mode regulator, then you would use the switching frequency. Look up the table and you get the effective ESR at the frequency you are operating at.

Comment: A capacitor is not only a capacitor. It "contains" (here) also a serial resistance and a serial inductance. So you can see that this component is a capacitor below ~500 MHz , a serial tank circuit at ~1GHz, and it is an "inductance" above ~1.5 Ghz ... If you use long wire, tank frequency will be "lower" ... .

Answer (score 2):

Just go to the Kemet website, enter the number of the part, select the part and look at the interactive graphs on their website such as [this one](https://www.kemet.com/en/us/capacitors/ceramic/product/C0603C101K5RACAUTO.html): -

[image]

The data on their site is usually much better than what appears on the data sheets.

> *Is there a frequency I should be basing it on?*

It depends entirely on what you are hoping to glean. Most people will look at the lowest ESR point (around 27 MHz) and use that value but, you may have more specialist requirements that dictate you are also interested in dielectric losses and, at a different frequency.

Comment: Kemet's online graphs are pretty good, but be sure to measure actual parts if it's important to your design. I've found slight to gross differences between their graphs and actual capacitors, mainly in capacitance versus DC bias voltage.

Answer (score 2):

Capacitors are modeled as an RLC network, with Equivalent Series Resistance, or ESR, representing the series R at a given condition (frequency, DC bias, etc.)

What that means is, capacitors have two reactive elements and one non-reactive element, the ESR. The ESR represents dielectric and other resistive behavior that vary with frequency. The K-SIM impedance and ESL chart for this cap shows that relationship, [here](https://ksim3.kemet.com/capacitor-simulation?pn=C0603C101K5RACAUTO).

How to use this information? ESR not only influences the cap's behavior as an AC pass element (affecting its 'Q' factor), but also how much AC it can handle. This is because the ESR will cause loss, and thus, heating, when subject to an AC signal.

This heating is of great interest when dynamic currents are very large, such as those seen by electrolytic caps on switching power supply outputs.

Related: [what does Loss Tangent means in capacitor?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/437484/what-does-loss-tangent-means-in-capacitor)

And again, how would you use this information? Depends what you care about. For a tuned filter, where you care about the value and its Q, you would probably best use the SPICE model for this cap to predict how it would behave. For bypassing, you would estimate your AC component and apply that frequency to the ESL graph to estimate dissipation in the cap.